# What programming language is used to design google analytics(Charts Section)?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, google-analytics

I just want to know that which languages or tech. did google use to **View charts and statistics**?.

is it flex or flash with actionscript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex is developed over flash platform. Whatever you do with flex can do using flash, but with more work. Flex exported is an also swf;

And actionscript is what make the flash functionality.

Probably google analytics is developed in Flex, but we can not know. We can be sure that today is flash and actionscript.

Answer (score 0):

That's sort of like asking: Did Google use Flash or Flash? While Flash and Flex are different from a developer's perspective, the browser sees the same SWF either way.

Flex would seem to me to be the natural choice from a development perspective, since it is more geared toward data-driven development. However, Flash CS5 is tremendously robust and probably equally capable... I think it probably just depends on the engineer's preference.

In the end, I have no idea what Google used. But, does it really matter? You can achieve the same result in either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tell if Flash is being used just right click on the browser and you will see whether the application is Flash based.  Flex is an actionscript library that runs on Flash. For RIA you can do plain javascript using maybe library like jQuery, or Flex/Actionscript, or GWT.  Those are the main ones out there for RIA in a broser.